# DockerHub registry host for private images

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have a private repository on DockerHub, and I'm trying to understand where does the docker daemon search for my image when I try to pull it via `docker pull myusername/image`.

This is important since my machine is restricted by firewall, and I have to permit dockerhub's host manually. I did allow dockerhub.com which is probably why I can pull official images like MongoDB etc., but it doesn't seem to work for **private** repos. It even works for my public ones, but not for private.

Question is - does anybody know why the host for the private repositories registry is different than others? And what is the host?